# Is it possible to check if a SQLite database is locked using the SQLiteConnection library

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using SQLiteConnection to access a sqlite file Firefox generates. My goal is to use this C# console application to find all installed extensions.

Here is the problem, Firefox locks the database on it's first start up, and also whenever I install a new extension. It unlocks the database when I restart Firefox, but I would like to simply not even try to read from the database when it's locked.

As my question asks, is it possible to check if the database is locked?

Here is some code for reading from the database:

```
    if (File.Exists(profilePath))
        {
            //Connect to the DB.
            string connectionPath = @"Data Source=" + profilePath;
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath))
            {
                //Create the command to retrieve the data.
                SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                //Open the connection.
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection Reuslt Code: " + connection.ResultCode());
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection State: " + connection.State.ToString());

                    //Get the tables.
                    DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
                    //Prepare the query to retreive all the add ons.
                    string query = "SELECT name as 'Extension_Name', id as 'extID', updateDate as 'Date' FROM addon";
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //Retreive the dataset using the command.
                    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "addon");

                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["addon"].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Get the date from the query.
                        long entryDateTicks = (long)ds.Tables["addon"].Rows[i].ItemArray[2];
                        //Add the ticks to the unix date. Devide by 1000 to convert ms to seconds.
                        DateTime unixTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                        DateTime entryDate = unixTime.AddSeconds(entryDateTicks / 1000);

                        //Add the data to a list/
                        addonList.Add(new FirefoxAddonEntry(
                            ds.Tables["addon"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()
                            , ds.Tables["addon"].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString()
                            , entryDate
                            ));
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error when opening the firefox sqlite file.");
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The extensions file does not exists.");
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to use FireFox it's database?

Comment: I'm sorry if I miss-understnad you, but if you are asking if I would like to use Firefox while reading from its' database, the answer is yes.

Comment: It isn't possible to read/write to fireFox database, you should create a database for the plugin/extension itself, so you can determine when it is locked yes or no.

Comment: It is possible to read from the database most of the time, Firefox only locks the Database when it is updating or installing extensions. Firefox unlocks the Database when Firefox is restarted(Which is a reason why some extensions require a restart).

I guess I could copy the database, but I can't just create my own.

Let me specify that I am using a Database that Firefox generates to store its' information about the users installed extensions, so I couldn't just create my own database.

Comment: I'am using a sqlitedatabase for my c# application and I make use of Transactions, it is way safer to use and it will prevent the locks.

Comment: That is interesting, but I only need to read from the database. In those examples they are inserting new values into the database. Any way to read from a database in a transaction?

Comment: I will add how to in an answer, since it allows me to show code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction looks a follow:

```
     using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
     {
                    connection.Open();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection Reuslt Code: " + connection.ResultCode());
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection State: " +                 connection.State.ToString());

                    //Get the tables.
                    DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
                    //Prepare the query to retreive all the add ons.
                    string query = "SELECT name as 'Extension_Name', id as 'extID', updateDate as 'Date' FROM addon";
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //Retreive the dataset using the command.
                    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "addon");

                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["addon"].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Get the date from the query.
                        long entryDateTicks = (long)ds.Tables["addon"].Rows[i].ItemArray[2];
                        //Add the ticks to the unix date. Devide by 1000 to convert ms to seconds.
                        DateTime unixTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
                        DateTime entryDate = unixTime.AddSeconds(entryDateTicks / 1000);

                        //Add the data to a list/
                        addonList.Add(new FirefoxAddonEntry(
                            ds.Tables["addon"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()
                            , ds.Tables["addon"].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString()
                            , entryDate
                            ));
                    }

         tran.Complete();
     }
```

Can you try changing your code to code above?

Comment: Where did you find the TransactionScope class? Is it a different library?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am stuck using .NET 2.0

Comment: It should be available for 2.0 as I read page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It is saying that it does not exist in the System namespace.

Comment: So I added the file I needed to my reference. When I run the program I get this error:

DllNotFoundException was unhandled
Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: The transaction library you are using does not play well with the sqlite library. It causes a lot of problems.